# My autocomplete plugin showing results only after the second keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am using [the autocomplete materialize css plugin](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#autocomplete) .

Everything works fine but i'm facing a little issue.

So when i call the autocomplete outside an event handler, just like showed in the [documentation](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#autocomplete) , the dropdown content list show up normally. For ex : If i'm just typing `A` then all results starting with an `A` will appear.

However, i need to put the autocomplete function inside a `keyup` event trigger in order to process some ajax requests. Everything works well except that the dropdown appears only after the second keyup.

So for exemple, in the first case (outside the event handler), if i want to search Apple, then i just need to type "A". But for the second case (inside jquery keyup event handler), i will need to Type "Ap" because nothing appears after the first keyup.

How can i make my keyup event handler take into account when i type the first character ?

Thanks for helping.

Outside the keyup event handler

```js
 $('.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    data: results
  });
```

Inside keyup event handler

```js
$('.autocomplete').keyup(function(e){

        $.ajax({
            url:"urladress",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success : function(result){
           
                $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
                    data: result
                });
            }
        })
        
    })
```

Comment: Try ditching the `async: false`.

Comment: Already done. It's not related to ajax. It even happens when the result is a local variable

Comment: Have you tried a `console.log` in your `keyup` function to see if it's firing when it should?

Comment: yes. the keyup is fired according to the console.log

Comment: Also, see if you can find a way to initialize the auto-complete with empty data before the user types, and *update* it instead of re-creating it on every keystroke. I have a suspicion initializing it after the first keystroke means it gets created in an inactive state, and the *second* keystroke (which is the *first* keystroke the autocomplete existed for) is what makes the autocomplete show up.

Comment: Yes i've tried to initialize just before the keyup with an empty object. But still the same issue. I think it's related with the autocomplete plugin itself. The only way to make it works perfectly is process it outside the keyup. So it means the object should be build before the jquery document be ready. I think but i have no idea about how i can make an ajax request inside a keyup event handler before the document be ready